# Sequence existing for a set of conditions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

> Let function $f$ is continuous and limited on the interval $(x_0, +\infty)$.
>
> Prove that $\forall \ T\in\mathbb R$, $\exists$ a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with  $\lim_{n \to\infty}{x_n} = +\infty $ such that:
>
> $$\lim_{n \to\infty} (f(x_n+T) - f(x_n)) = 0$$

If $f$ is sinus, for example, it doesn't seem to be true...

I have no thoughts to prove it.

Comment: It's "prove" not "proove" and "number" is ambiguous (natural? rational? real? complex? ordinal?).

Comment: I think it's real. In task no info about it

Comment: Yes I assumed "real" in my answer, but it's good for you to figure out and specify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Take any $T \ge 0$. Let $g(x) = f(x+T) - f(x)$ for each $x \in [x_0,\infty)$. Then $g$ is continuous on $[x_0,\infty)$. Also, for every $x \ge x_0$ such that $g(x) > 0$, and any $ε > 0$, there is some $y > x$ such that $g(y) \le ε$, otherwise $f(x+kT) - f(x) > kε$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, which contradicts the boundedness of $f$. By intermediate value theorem we can strengthen this to $0 \le g(y) \le ε$. Similarly for every $x \ge x_0$ such that $g(x) < 0$, and any $ε > 0$, there is some $y > x$ such that $-ε \le g(y) \le 0$. Using this we can now construct each $x_n$ by induction, and then use the axiom of dependent choice to obtain the desired sequence.

Answer (score 0):

As $x_0$ might be confused as if it's a term in the sequence, I'm rephrasing the question as follows:

> Assume that $\displaystyle f:( a,\infty )\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is
> continuous and bounded. Prove that, given $\displaystyle T$, there
> exists a sequence $\displaystyle \{x_{n}\}$ such that $\displaystyle \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } x_{n} =+\infty $ and $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\{f( x_{n} +T) -f( x_{n})\} =0$.

For what it's worth, I was doing my homework whence I came across this question and tried to look it up on [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cdisplaystyle%20%5Clim%20_%7Bn%5Crightarrow%20%5Cinfty%20%7D%5C%7Bf(%20x_%7Bn%7D%20%2BT)%20-f(%20x_%7Bn%7D)%5C%7D%20%3D0%24&p=2). I found this post scrolling dwon the second page of the search results, probably because there were some bugs in the MathJaX code which I fixed through an edit.

It took me quite some time to understand [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1795142/955582); I am just expanding on the "hint" given by [user21820](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/21820/user21820) so that future readers have an easy time :)

---

### Solution

WLOG, let $\displaystyle T\geqslant 0$.

Define $\displaystyle g( x) =f( x+T) -f( x)$ which is also continuous function $\displaystyle g:( a,\infty )\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. 
In case, $\displaystyle T< 0$, we would have defined $\displaystyle g( x) =f( x-T) -f( x)$.

Let $\displaystyle \varepsilon $ be an arbitrary positive real number.

For every $\displaystyle b >a$ with $\displaystyle g( b)  >\varepsilon $, there is some $\displaystyle c >b$ such that $\displaystyle g( c) \leq \varepsilon $.

Otherwise if $\displaystyle g( x)  >\varepsilon $ for all $\displaystyle x >b$, the sequence $\displaystyle \{f( b+kT)\}_{k\ \in \ \mathbb{N}}$ will be unbounded:

$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}
 & f( b+kT)\\
 &  \begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
=\underbrace{f( b+kT) -f( b+( k-1) T)}_{=\ g( b+( k-1) T)}\\
\\
\quad +\underbrace{f( b+( k-1) T) -f( b+( k-2) T)}_{=\ g( b+( k-2) T)}\\
\quad +\ \dotsc \\
\\
\quad +\underbrace{f( b+T) -f( b)}_{=\ g( b+T)} +f( b)
\end{array}\\
 & \geqslant k \varepsilon +f( b)\\
 & \rightarrow \infty \ \text{as } k\rightarrow \infty 
\end{aligned}$

which contradictis that $\displaystyle f$ is bounded.

In the interval $\displaystyle [ b,c]$, we have $\displaystyle g( b)  >\varepsilon $ and $\displaystyle g( c) \leqslant \varepsilon $. In case $\displaystyle g( c) < 0$, by continuity of $\displaystyle f$, we are assured that $\displaystyle g([ b,c])$ fully contains $\displaystyle ( 0,\varepsilon )$.

Thus, we can pick our $\displaystyle c$ such that $\displaystyle g( c)  >0$.

To recollect, for every $\displaystyle b\in ( a,\infty )$ with $\displaystyle g( b)  >0$, we have, $\displaystyle c >b$ such that $\displaystyle 0< g( c) < g( b)$.

Similarly, we can show that for every $\displaystyle b\in ( a,\infty )$ with $\displaystyle g( b) < 0$, we have, $\displaystyle c >b$ such that $\displaystyle 0\geq g( c) \geq g( b)$.

Now, we can construct the sequence $\displaystyle \{x_{n}\}$ by taking some $\displaystyle x_{1} \in ( a,\infty )$ with $\displaystyle g( x_{1})  >0$ and obtaining $\displaystyle x_{2}  >x_{1}$ such that $\displaystyle 0< g( x_{2}) < g( x_{1})$. Similarly, we can pick $\displaystyle x_{3}$, $\displaystyle x_{4}$,$\displaystyle \dotsc $and so on.

In case, $\displaystyle g( x) < 0$ for all $\displaystyle x\in ( a,\infty )$, we can construct the sequence $\displaystyle \{x_{n}\}$ by taking some $\displaystyle x_{1} \in ( a,\infty )$ with $\displaystyle g( x_{1}) < 0$ and obtaining $\displaystyle x_{2}  >x_{1}$ such that $\displaystyle 0 >g( x_{2})  >g( x_{1})$. Similarly, we can pick $\displaystyle x_{3}$, $\displaystyle x_{4}$,$\displaystyle \dotsc $ and so on.